Calculate $\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{16r^2-1}$ using the Fourier-Series of $|\sin(x)|$
I have the following problem:
Calculate $\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{16r^2-1}$ using the Fourier-Series of $|\sin(x)|$
For this I already calculated the Fourier-Series of $|\sin(x)|$ to be
$$|\sin(x)|=\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(2rx)}{4r^2-1}$$
Part of the task was to calculate the value of $\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4r^2-1}$ which I calculated and checked to be $1/2$ by setting $x=0$. Now I am supposed to calculate the value of $\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{16r^2-1}$ by setting $x=\pi/2$ but I struggle to get to a result: when I set $x=π/2$ I have: $1=\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(r\pi)}{4r^2-1}=\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^r}{4r^2-1}$. I don't know how to get to $\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty\frac{1}{16r^2-1}$ from there and how to deal with the oscilating term.
Does anybody know what to do?
